# How to make VS code encode/decode Japanese Characters correctly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, encoding

I am having a wired issue with Japanese Characters in VS code.

What I am doing is simply create a string in Japanese and display it.

Here is the code:

```
str = "こんにちは" 
print(str)
```

And this works perfectly fine with terminal

```
>>> str = "こんにちは" 
>>> print(str)
こんにちは
```

My terminal encoding is cp932:

```
PS D:\WorkSpace\> chcp
現在のコード ページ: 932
```

However if I create a python script and use the same code the output is completely different.

```
# coding: cp932
str = "こんにちは" 
print(str)
```

Output is

```
PS D:\WorkSpace\> python test.py
､ｳ､ﾋ､ﾁ､ﾏ
```

If I remove the cp932 coding part at the begining then I got the following error:

```
File "test.py", line 2
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xa4' in file test.py on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

If I use 'utf-8' as the coding for the script file, I got the following error:

```
  File "test.py", line 2
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa4 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I am completely out of mind why this is happening, does anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the default encoding of my vscode has been set to GBK and that's the reason.

After I changed the encoding to utf-8 the issue is resolved.

Hope this can help someone in the future.